# How to login drupal to magento single sign on?

Tags: authentication-authorization

I want to login drupal to magento and magento to drupal . can any body help me how it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: This question has already been asked: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84767/magento-drupal-sso-single-sign-on